# Stopping an animation then restarting it

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have no idea how I can stop this animation when the mouse is over it

http://jsfiddle.net/xRcwH/14/

Answer (score 2):

Is this the effect you need : http://jsfiddle.net/xRcwH/24/ ?

Comment: I really dislike it, when people write oneliners without any explanation. We are all here to learn, so just explain what you did and why (and post some of the code here in case the fiddle goes down) and then you'll get my upvote.

Comment: I think the animation is not exactly the same - the marquee text starts in the middle of the screen and finishes farther left. OP's marquee wraps around the screen as it's being animated.

Comment: @Christoph: I wasn't sure that I have the answer that Peli Lipe needs, That's why my answer is a single line question. If the Q confirms that my answer is good, I can explain what I did there.

Answer (score 2):

The following should *hopefully* work like you want it to:

```
var $marquee;

var reset = function() {
    "use strict";
    $marquee.css("margin-left", "0%");
    $marquee.animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 4000, 'linear', reset);
};

var func = function() {
    "use strict";
    $marquee = $("#marquee");
    $marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "width": "100%"});
    $marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
    $marquee.find("span").css({ "width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align": "right" });
    $marquee.append($marquee.find("span").clone());
    $marquee.wrapInner("<div>");
    $marquee.find("div").css("width", "200%");
    reset.call($marquee.find("div"));
};

$(function() {
    "use strict";
    func();

    $marquee.hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 4000, 'linear', reset);
        }
    );
});
```

See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xRcwH/27/

I have cleaned up your code a bit and moved things around. The `reset` function **should not be** declared in the function `func` so I moved that out.

Furthermore I changed:

```
marquee.find("span").css({ "width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align":"center" });
```

to

```
$marquee.find("span").css({ "width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align": "right" });
```

as this makes it animate over the whole screen.

Lastly I'm using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) because this is what it is made for, [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is the same as doing:

`$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

Comment: has some speed issues after mouseout

Answer (score 1):

You should also post your code here, but here is what makes it stop:

```
$(this).find('div').stop();
```

instead of

```
$this.stop();
```

Because the animation is on the div inside the marquee.